# SocketException existing connection forcibly closed with Flurl

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, flurl

I'm attempting to query the public NPPES NPI registry using [Flurl](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/) as my HTTP client library, version 2.4.2.

After 4-5 successful async requests (debugging by stepping through each request in the loop) it always fails with a SocketException that the connection was forcibly closed. I'm assuming the API is rate limited, but slowing down the requests doesn't seem to be working. Here is my relevant code.

```
static async Task<Result> GetNpiEntry(string npiNumber)
{
    var npiEntry = await "https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov"
        .AppendPathSegment("api/")
        .SetQueryParams(new { version = "2.1", number = npiNumber }).GetJsonAsync<RootObject>();

    return npiEntry.results[0];
}
```

and the loop calling it with a hefty sleep between requests.

```
List<Result> npiResults = new List<Result>(npiTable.Rows.Count);

foreach (DataRow row in npiTable.Rows)
{
    Result npiEntry = Task.Run(() => GetNpiEntry((string)row[0])).Result;
    npiResults.Add(npiEntry);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Here's the actual exception.

```
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Is there some more appropriate way for me to debug or do this?
I imagine I'd need to rate limit the client, but shouldn't a generous wait time between requests work at least for debugging?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your code and detailed error info with your question, it makes it easier to answer. :)

Comment: Can you make your `Task.Run` lambda `async` and then `await` the call to `GetNpiEntry`. Ie: `Task.Run( async ( ) => await GetNpiEntry`

Comment: @WBuck I can't add that as it fails to compile, the foreach loop is nestled within the ```static void Main(string[] args) {}``` entry point.

Adding another sleep before the Task.Run() call allows it to complete ~1000 requests before hitting this error, but it hits it none the less.

Comment: I'm posting an answer give me a second

Comment: WBuck's answer is correct. I added some detail and a repro in mine. Hope that's helpful @tNAPA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not Flurl or API throttling, but blocking on an async call (as @WBuck said).

The best practice is to avoid `.Result` and even `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Those and `Task.Run()` are all examples of mixing sync and async code. There are good articles online for why this is bad - search for `.net mix sync async` for more background info.

The correct solution is to use async "all the way down". Pretty much every entry point can be marked `async` now, including console apps.

This works on my machine even **without** the sleeps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;

namespace SO_59567958
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ids = new[] { "1023086709", "1659325215", "1912946427", "1740219450", "1750497640", "1538260823", "1275625626", "1144303488", "1205919107", "1730281890", "1568453561" };
            Console.WriteLine($"Retrieving {ids.Length} NPI records...");

            var npiResults = new List<Result>();
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                var retrievedFromApi = await GetNpiEntry(id);
                npiResults.Add(retrievedFromApi);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            npiResults.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Number));
        }

        static async Task<Result> GetNpiEntry(string npiNumber)
        {
            var npiEntry = await "https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov"
                .AppendPathSegment("api/")
                .SetQueryParams(new { version = "2.1", number = npiNumber })
                .GetJsonAsync<RootObject>();

            return npiEntry.Results[0];
        }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int ResultCount { get; set; }

        public IReadOnlyList<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to do the await async calls correctly. However this example still fails after enough iterations with the same socket error.

I have a less useful implementation of this (VB.NET generated by another program) that could complete querying the entire data set (~2000 entries for this) in about 2 minutes without error or any sleeps, but the connection is forcibly closed using this after a few dozen queries.

Comment: I think I'm able to handle it well enough by just catching the exception and waiting before trying again, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! For more complex retry policies, check out: http://www.thepollyproject.org/

Answer (score 1):

You're not `await`ing the call to `GetNpiEntry` in the `Task.Run` lambda. If the call to `GetNpiEntry` executed synchronously then you have no problems. If the call to `GetNpiEntry` executes asynchronously then the `Task.Run` lambda will not `await` its result.

Try the following instead:

```
foreach (DataRow row in npiTable.Rows)
{
    Result npiEntry = Task.Run( async () => await GetNpiEntry((string)row[0])).GetAwaiter( ).GetResult( );
    npiResults.Add(npiEntry);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

I also see you're using `.NetCore` so you should be able to use the following `main` instead.

```
static async Task Main( string[ ] args )
```

This allows you to use `await` within `Main` .

Comment: Thanks that does work for processing the results, however after (in this case 101) requests the socket is closed by the remote host and the exception is thrown. How should I deal with reopening a new socket when this occurs, and more directly why does this fail while I can retrieve approximately 2000 NPIs (sequentially) without issue in  ~ 2 minutes through a less programmatic client, but waiting several seconds between requests is bound to fail after a few minutes in this C# version.

Comment: Network exceptions happen. Its just one of those things that can and do often fail. It's up to you to `catch` the `Exception`. Once caught you need to decide how you want to recover from it. Often I'll have "retry" logic which will attempt the same call `N` times on a failure. Usually I first try to re-connect with the `remote` and upon successfully connecting I will re-issue my request.

Comment: A simple try {} catch { wait and retry } seems like it might be enough. Thank you.